excel formula: count unique values only
Ive got a table similar to the following (it contains blanks):



Column A
Column B




date 1
value 1


date 2
value 1


date 3
value 2


date 4
value 3


date 5
value 1



value 4



Now I want to count the value in column B on a weekly basis. This formular is working in general but it counts every value:
=countifs('All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$A:$A;">="&B$2;'All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$A:$A;"<="&B$3)
So in this case it would count 6 although value 1 appears 3 times. Instead it should count a total of 4.
If a value appears more then once in a week, I want it to count it only once.
My approach isnt working and is counting zero. Whats wrong?
=count(unique(filter('All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$B$2:$B; ('All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$A$2:$A >= B$2) * ('All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$A$2:$A <= B$3) * ('All time Nebenrechnung Influencer Marketing'!$B$2:$B <> "")))) 

Post few dummy data and show your desired result.

@Harun24hr I edited my question, hopes this clarifies

There are two ways to count distinct values:
If your Excel supports the Unique() function, you might simply:
=COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:A9))

If not, you might use the following neat trick:
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A9;A1:A9))

Have fun, here's a screenshot:


We could use FREQUENCY also (Count unique values among duplicates - Microsoft Support); since it works on numbers, we convert the values to indices to the unique values first.
Enter the following in a cell with enough rows and columns to show the result:
=LET(
values, B1:B6,
unique_values, UNIQUE(values),
indices_for_values, MATCH(values,unique_values,0),
frequencies,DROP(
FREQUENCY(indices_for_values, indices_for_values),
-1),
counts, FILTER(frequencies, frequencies>0),
HSTACK(unique_values, counts)
)



This formula also use UNIQUE but instead FILTER the TOCOL function. In your formula EXCEL cannot accept the expansion of a range/open ended range.(maybe it's a typo)
Formula
=COUNT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF((L25:L30>=P23)*(L25:L30<=Q23),M25:M30,1/0),3)))


The simplest formula seems at least for me is this:



A
B
C
D
E




1900.01.10.
1

Start
Stop


1900.01.11.
1

1900.01.11.
1900.01.14.


1900.01.12.
2

Unique val.
3


1900.01.13.
3





1900.01.14.
1





1900.01.15.
4






In cell E3:
=COUNT(UNIQUE(IF((A1:A6>=D2)*(A1:A6<=E2),B1:B6,"")))
